# Most efficient way to get values from a dictionary into a set

Tags: python, dictionary, set, set-comprehension

I cant seem to figure out how to write the following into a one line of code, using set comprehension.  If its not possible is there a faster way to do what I am trying to do here?  Basically just getting all the values of a dictionary into a set.  Some values can be an empty set.  A simple example is below

```
d = {1:set(),2:{1,2,3},3:{4}}

t = set()

for k, v in d.items():
   if len(v) > 0:
      t.update(v)

print(t)
```

output

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

Comment: I see no t here...

Comment: sorry, forgot to put t in there.  Please see update.  Its basically just a set

Comment: Why not just `t = set.union(*d.values())`?

Comment: You can do `for v in d.values()`, and the `if len(v) > 0` is not really necessary.

Comment: I did try set.union before but wasnt getting the answer.   Apparently i was missing the * in it.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest is probably:

```
>>> set.union(*d.values())
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

There's no need to special-case an empty set in the values.  Folding an empty set into the union makes no difference to the result, and checking for the length in advance in Python code is slower than just letting `set.union()` figure it out.

### WITH A SET COMPREHENSION

You can do it with a set comprehension too, but I expect this way would be significantly slower (although I haven't timed it):

```
>>> {x for oneset in d.values() for x in oneset}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Comment: As i mentioned above, I did try set.union before but wasnt getting the answer. Apparently i was missing the * in it thats why it wasnt working.  Thanks.  What does the * doing that it doesnt work without it?

Comment: @user1179317 See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the `union` thing, you could use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

d = {1:set(),2:{1,2,3},3:{4}}
set(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
>>> {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Tim Peters's and jdehesa's answers are faster than using a set comprehension because they avoid the explicit double `for` loop running at Python speed. But here's how to do it with a set comprehension:

```
d = {1:set(), 2:{1,2,3}, 3:{4}}
t = {v for u in d.values() for v in u}
print(t)
```

**output**

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```